How do I resolve treesitter error on Windows?

I keep getting this error after trying to set up treesitter. I've seen advice online saying to read the Windows support page for treesitter, but I can't seem to understand what's going on in the support page and how it helps my problem.
This is my Neovim config if it helps. It is very messy but I plan to separate the config into plugin, colorscheme, etc., as soon as I get a better understanding of lua + nvim
vim.cmd("set number")
vim.cmd("set expandtab")
vim.cmd("set tabstop=4")
vim.cmd("set softtabstop=2")
vim.cmd("set shiftwidth=2")

-- Bootstrap lazy.nvim
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local lazyrepo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  local out = vim.fn.system({ "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", "--branch=stable", lazyrepo, lazypath })
  if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
    vim.api.nvim_echo({
      { "Failed to clone lazy.nvim:\n", "ErrorMsg" },
      { out, "WarningMsg" },
      { "\nPress any key to exit..." },
    }, true, {})
    vim.fn.getchar()
    os.exit(1)
  end
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-- Set mapleader
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.maplocalleader = "\\"

-- Setup lazy.nvim
require("lazy").setup({
  spec = {
    { "catppuccin/nvim", name = "catppuccin", priority = 1000 },
    {
      'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.8',
      dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' }
    },
    {"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", build = ":TSUpdate"}
  },
  install = { colorscheme = { "habamax" } },
  checker = { enabled = true },
})

-- Telescope keybindings
local builtin = require("telescope.builtin")
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-p>', builtin.find_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})

require 'nvim-treesitter.install'.prefer_git = false
require 'nvim-treesitter.install'.compilers = { "clang", "gcc" }
local config = require("nvim-treesitter.configs")
config.setup({
  ensure_installed = {"c", "java", "python"},
  highlight = { enable = true },
  indent = { enable = true },
})

-- Catppuccin colorscheme setup
require("catppuccin").setup()
vim.cmd.colorscheme "catppuccin"

I just tried reading the support page but I do not know what's going on still. I think it has something to do with a C compiler? I can't really find a page online that describes the problem and goes through step by step to fix it.

Please do not post text error messages as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text and include it formatted as code in your question.
